# how can I add a newline using logic app or powerautomate?

Tags: power-automate

I'm trying to add newline in String using Logic App. But I got nothing interesting.

That is what I got:

```
ios-youtube, keepassium-ios, markmcguill-strongbox, Office-Word, microsoft-azureauthenticator, microsoft-scmx, Office-Excel, microsoft-skydrive, Office-Powerpoint, spotify-client, Office-Word, microsoft-onenote, uhhhmagine-flannl, robbie-HomeAssistant, rdc-ios, microsoft-skydrive, skype-teams, miketigas-OnionBrowser, netflix-Netflix, bjoerndemming-aldisued, delius-klasing-bike-app, delius-klasing-tour, heise-ch-magazin, heise-ct-magazin, heise-news4, online-norma, sec-lidl, delius-klasing-ios, robbie-HomeAssistant
```

I tried these.

[image]

[image]

and I want the result in this form.

```
- ios-youtube, 
- keepassium-ios, 
- markmcguill-strongbox, 
- Office-Word, 
- microsoft-azureauthenticator,
- microsoft-scmx, Office-Excel,
- microsoft-skydrive, 
- Office-Powerpoint, 
- spotify-client, 
- Office-Word, 
- microsoft-onenote, 
- uhhhmagine-flannl, 
- robbie-HomeAssistant, 
- rdc-ios, 
- microsoft-skydrive, 
- skype-teams, 
- miketigas-OnionBrowser, 
- netflix-Netflix, 
- bjoerndemming-aldisued, 
- delius-klasing-bike-app, 
- delius-klasing-tour, 
- heise-ch-magazin, 
- heise-ct-magazin, 
- heise-news4, 
- online-norma, 
- sec-lidl, 
- delius-klasing-ios, 
- robbie-HomeAssistant
```

Comment: I remember having the issue, but can't remember which logicapp I had it in. Have you tried opening notepad++ enable special characters, then select from the end of one line to beginning of the next line. Then copy using [ctrl]+[c] and paste it into the concat instead of \n. Another one is to also try \r\n instead of just \n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

**`Design:`**

[image]

Then initialized an empty variable and the composed variable 1 with `split(variables('var1'),',')`:

[image]

Then in ForEach loop taken input (compose 1 output) then in action used concat in `composeconcat('- ',items('For_each'))` and then appended var2 and then joined it with new line(just press enter):

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

**`Codeview:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@split(variables('var1'),',')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_array_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "var2",
                            "value": "@outputs('Compose_2')"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Compose_2": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    },
                    "Compose_2": {
                        "inputs": "@concat('- ',items('For_each'))",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Compose"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@outputs('Compose')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var1",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "ios-youtube, keepassium-ios, markmcguill-strongbox, Office-Word, microsoft-azureauthenticator, microsoft-scmx, Office-Excel, microsoft-skydrive, Office-Powerpoint, spotify-client, Office-Word, microsoft-onenote, uhhhmagine-flannl, robbie-HomeAssistant, rdc-ios, microsoft-skydrive, skype-teams, miketigas-OnionBrowser, netflix-Netflix, bjoerndemming-aldisued, delius-klasing-bike-app, delius-klasing-tour, heise-ch-magazin, heise-ct-magazin, heise-news4, online-norma, sec-lidl, delius-klasing-ios, robbie-HomeAssistant\n"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var2",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Join": {
                "inputs": {
                    "from": "@variables('var2')",
                    "joinWith": "\n"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Join"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This basic flow shows you a fairly simple approach that should get you over the line.

#### Flow

[image: Flow]

The expression in the second step looks like this (noting the hyphen at the start in the image to cater for the very first record) ...

```
replace(variables('String'), ', ', ',
- ')
```

... but when I entered it, I put it in like this ...

```
    replace(variables('String'), ', ', ',\n- ')
```

To achieve that, you need to go into the **Code View** and edit the definition and change `\\n` to `\n`.  Reason being, when you enter it through the designer, it's not what you're after.  The code view will looks like this ...

```
"Initialize_Enhanced_String": {
    "inputs": {
        "variables": [
            {
                "name": "Enhanced String",
                "type": "string",
                "value": "- @{replace(variables('String'), ', ', ',\\n- ')}"
            }
        ]
    },
    "runAfter": {
        "Initialize_String": [
            "Succeeded"
        ]
    },
    "type": "InitializeVariable"
}
```

... and that isn't correct.  Remove the second slash will get you across the line.

#### Result

[image: Result]